# how to search in multiple columns using search_fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have multiple columns in a model.  I am attaching a screenshot:
[image]

I can search only IP address but I also want to search in Department and location. Any idea how to solve this, here is my admin.py looks like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pages.models import Post, Device, DeviceType, DeviceModel, Ipaddress, DeviceGroup, Location,Department,Comment
from django_admin_listfilter_dropdown.filters import DropdownFilter, RelatedDropdownFilter


class IpaddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('ipaddress',)}

        search_fields = ['ipaddress','department', 'location',]


        list_display = ('ipaddress', 'machinename', 'user', 'department','location','updated',)
        list_display_links =('ipaddress', 'machinename', 'user', 'department','location','updated',)

#        autocomplete_fields = ['department', 'location',]


        list_filter = (
        ('user', DropdownFilter),
        ('department', RelatedDropdownFilter),
        ('location', RelatedDropdownFilter),

    )
        list_per_page = 100

class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']

class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['description']
```

Following line is giving me error:

```
search_fields = ['ipaddress','department', 'location',]
```

The error i am seeing is:

> C:\Users\mohiuddin_rana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1087, in build_lookup
>           raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
>       django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
>       [23/Sep/2018 23:45:19] "GET /admin/pages/ipaddress/?q=dev HTTP/1.1" 500 155606

Here is the IP model in python.py

```
lass Ipaddress(models.Model):
    ipaddress=models.CharField("Ip Address",max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    machinename=models.CharField("Machine Name",max_length=500)
    user=models.CharField("User",max_length=200)
    department= models.ForeignKey("Department", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location= models.ForeignKey("Location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateField("Date Updated",null=True)
    note =models.TextField()
    class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'IP Management'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ipaddress[:50]
```

How to search in multiple columns?

Comment: Can you post the `Ipaddress` model?

Answer (score 1):

In your Ipaddress model, **location** and **department** are foreign keys on which you want to search. To specify search on foreign key field you have to specify the field on that model as :

```
search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']
```

as given in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields).

In your case it could be location__name and department__name , if you want to search by their names.